# Ask related question (question inheritance?)

Tags: feature-request, questions

I'd like to be able to as a question as an extension of a previous SO question.

Kind of like a question inheritance.  New question extends Old question.

Currently this is done by placing a link somewhere in the question text, but it'd be neat if it were more formal.  Then you could have links from 'base class' questions that point to all the questions that extend it, without having to manually update everything.

Comment: Screen shots and visual examples of implementation ideas are feature request gold.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asking a follow-up question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/asking-a-follow-up-question)

Comment: Would love to upvote this but can't (yet).  I see this as a way to allow StackOverFlow to get deeper while avoiding the appearance of duplicate questions.  I say appearance because although some questions are duplicates due to poor search or lazyness other exist because one question+answers can't be expected to answer every other permutation of that question.

Answer (score 6):

I find the current system works ok.  I like it when the linked related or reference questions are at the top of the new related question. As long as it is referenced/linked clearly in the "child" question, you should be good to go.

Comment: +1 let's not add to the feature bloat; sleek and simple works for this site.

Answer (score 2):

The only inherited questions that stick in my mind (there must be others, but I can't recall them just now) fall into two categories:

1. They are asked by the most clueless, persistently wrong-headed, take-take-take-and-never-give users in an effort to get us to solve their problems for them instead of just pointing them in the right direction
2. Are one adjective away from an existing question, and generally feel like the poster was anxious to post something--*anything*--and latched onto the first idea that presented itself.

I'm sure that there are legitimate uses for such a feature, but I suspect that it will be of most use to the users I least want to have around.

Count me as agin' it.

Comment: Downvotes to express simple disagreement are fair, especially on meta, but I do like to hear why. Please.

Comment: ftr I didn't downvote you, but I do disagree!  There's been more than one occassion where I've posted a simple question, got an answer, kept working, and then got stuck again on something still directly related to the first problem.  This is why I'm suggesting this feature.

Comment: @bobobobo: Yeah. I guessed as much. And I'm sure I must have seen it once or twice from others as well, but they are not the ones I recall. Could be confirmation bias, I guess.