# What should I do if I have a sub-question to someone else's already existing question?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

I didn't find the answer for a specific subquestion in a [general question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/442/202747), so I asked the subquestion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174640/202747), and it got closed as a duplicate. Since I already got the answer, I don't need to reopen it, but I didn't find any post with general guidelines for this specifically (there are similar questions on situation when the original, more general question is bad at all, such as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138198/202747), but I think rewording just for sake of one special case might be different).

Should I edit the original question? Or ask in a comment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ask related question (question inheritance)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25164/ask-related-question-question-inheritance)

Comment: @Wouter Not a duplicate, just related. That one is a feature request, this is just asking what he should do in this case.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, you're right. Related question was better. I haven't flagged/vote to close for duplicate though, it was just to mention that question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in the close message, you should open a new question:

> If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

But, in order to not make it a duplicate, you should link to the other question and tell us *specifically* what you don't understand. Asking a new question without referring to the other question and explaining why it doesn't solve your problem increases the chances that your new question will be simply marked as a duplicate of the original question.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I edit the original question?

No, do not edit the original question and add yours.

It is quite common to not find specific things on Meta especially when there are few good specific keywords to go on (there have been a few times I have failed to find things). Provided you don't do it intentionally, don't worry about your question being a duplicate - you weren't to know. There are people here on Meta with very good memories and probably an address book full of links, if you ask and it is a duplicate they will find it.

> Or ask in a comment?

Asking in a comment is also not good, there is no guarantee that anyone will see it or take notice of it, let alone answer it.