# Broaden a question

Tags: discussion, questions

I found a question on Stack Overflow, [Is there a command that includes files in a project of Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077816/is-there-a-command-that-includes-files-in-a-project-of-visual-studio-2010) that is interesting to me too, but with a slightly different focus.

It would somehow alter the original question or augment it, to include my thought in question to the question, but it would mostly add a duplicate to SO if I'm asking it again.

Would it be OK, to alter the question ( as a comment might not be regarded as a question ) or should one add a question with a link to the original?.

It is kind of a follow-up question, which is covered by [Asking a follow-up question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/asking-a-follow-up-question), but the author differs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a recent question, which is still gathering answers, and if your request is just a little broader, put a comment on the question, suggesting that answerers address your focus as well. (I see you just did this.)

If there's an answer that almost works in your case, it's ok to comment on it to ask “What if I change this detail?”. Be prepared to have no response (if the author of that answer doesn't know) or “it's different, ask a new question”.

For an old question, or for a new question if the answers don't turn out to help you, ask a new question. To avoid the new question being closed as a duplicate, be sure to indicate that you've done your homework beforehand. Write your question using the following form:

> “<Complete statement of problem>
>
> (This is a follow-up to <question>, which did not address <specifics of your situation>.”).

Do not edit someone else's question to broaden it unless you already know that all the answers to the original question would remain valid. (In which case, you wouldn't need to ask that broader question.)

Answer (score 8):

What's wrong with asking your own question?

Link to the existing one and as long as there is a difference it shouldn't get closed as a duplicate. Just make sure you're really clear about the difference in focus.

Answer (score 0):

When you're going to ask question, be sure it's not about the same thing. When it's asking for different thing, then you can ask it without fraud that it will be closed.